# How to get ElementHandle based on `innerText`?

Tags: puppeteer

I have a list of links, and want to `click` on one of them based on the name of the link. I can't accomplish this with selectors.

It would be nice to use something like `page.$eval` to get the ElementHandle of that item so I can then tap/click it.

The only other approach I can think of is getting the x/y coords within `$eval` and then manually clicking on clicking on the location. Seems tedious.

I posted this here per the guidelines, but LMK if we should open a PR on this.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered use the [`page.$$(selector)`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselector) to get all your target elments and then use [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to get the `linkName`, then do the check and click?

something like:

```
const targetLinks = await page.$$('yourLinkSelector');
for(let link of targetLinks){
  const linkName = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerHTML, link); 
  if (linkName === 'myFancyLinkToClick') {
    await link.click();
    // break if only 1 link click is needed.
    break;
  }
}
```

Hope it works for you.